# Combine JSON objects bases on the same value

Tags: javascript, json

I’m looking for a way to combine JSON objects if they have the same `address` value in them. Building off this [Combining JSON Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50567396/combining-duplicate-values-in-javascript-array) I have these two sample `JSON` files. Would love any suggestions thank you so much.

###### Before Combining:

```json
[
    {
        "saleNo": "86131",
        "address": "6562 Dagmar Haven Suite 593 Warner Robins WI, 68085-5440",
        "deliveryTo": "Earl Bruen"
    },
    {
        "saleNo": "82483",
        "address": "6562 Dagmar Haven Suite 593 Warner Robins WI, 68085-5440",
        "deliveryTo": "Harold Kuhn"
    },
    {
        "saleNo": "53731",
        "address": "33194 Royal Track Suite 501 Enid CO, 57355",
        "deliveryTo": "Kristopher Bayer"
    },
    {
        "saleNo": "12285",
        "address": "183 Lazaro Meadow Suite 841 Council Bluffs AL, 52499",
        "deliveryTo": "Cassandra Mueller"
    },
    {
        "saleNo": "23404",
        "address": "89319 Witting Green Suite 924 Portland MN, 74633-9170",
        "deliveryTo": "Chris Thiel Sr."
    },
    {
        "saleNo": "70528",
        "address": "2410 Zaria Forges Suite 936 St. Louis GA, 94962-5376",
        "deliveryTo": "Glenda Larson"
    }
]
```

###### After Combining:

```json
[
    {
        "saleNo": ["86131", "82483"],
        "address": "6562 Dagmar Haven Suite 593 Warner Robins WI, 68085-5440",
        "deliveryTo": ["Harold Kuhn", "Earl Bruen"]
    },
    {
        "saleNo": "53731",
        "address": "33194 Royal Track Suite 501 Enid CO, 57355",
        "deliveryTo": "Kristopher Bayer"
    },
    {
        "saleNo": "12285",
        "address": "183 Lazaro Meadow Suite 841 Council Bluffs AL, 52499",
        "deliveryTo": "Cassandra Mueller"
    },
    {
        "saleNo": "23404",
        "address": "89319 Witting Green Suite 924 Portland MN, 74633-9170",
        "deliveryTo": "Chris Thiel Sr."
    },
    {
        "saleNo": "70528",
        "address": "2410 Zaria Forges Suite 936 St. Louis GA, 94962-5376",
        "deliveryTo": "Glenda Larson"
    }
]
```

###### Sample Code:

```js
let data = [
    {
        "saleNo": "86131",
        "address": "6562 Dagmar Haven Suite 593 Warner Robins WI, 68085-5440",
        "deliveryTo": "Earl Bruen"
    },
    {
        "saleNo": "82483",
        "address": "6562 Dagmar Haven Suite 593 Warner Robins WI, 68085-5440",
        "deliveryTo": "Harold Kuhn"
    },
    {
        "saleNo": "53731",
        "address": "33194 Royal Track Suite 501 Enid CO, 57355",
        "deliveryTo": "Kristopher Bayer"
    },
    {
        "saleNo": "12285",
        "address": "183 Lazaro Meadow Suite 841 Council Bluffs AL, 52499",
        "deliveryTo": "Cassandra Mueller"
    },
    {
        "saleNo": "23404",
        "address": "89319 Witting Green Suite 924 Portland MN, 74633-9170",
        "deliveryTo": "Chris Thiel Sr."
    },
    {
        "saleNo": "70528",
        "address": "2410 Zaria Forges Suite 936 St. Louis GA, 94962-5376",
        "deliveryTo": "Glenda Larson"
    }
]

let result = Object.values(data.reduce((c, {address,numbers}) => {
  c[address] = c[address] || {address,numbers: []};
  c[address].numbers = c[address].numbers.concat(Array.isArray(numbers) ? numbers : [numbers]); 
  return c;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve].

Comment: @Andy code has been added

Comment: Basically, you want to group/collate/pivot by (exact!) address?

Comment: @skreutzer yes that’s basically it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution uses:

- reduce to create a map of addresses, that contains maps of saleNo and deliveryTo (in order to weed out duplicates)
- Object.entries and map to to convert the nested maps to the desired output

This reduce and map solution is faster than the nested for loops approach for large datasets, e.g. O(2n) vs. O(n*n)

```js
let data = [ { "saleNo": "86131", "address": "6562 Dagmar Haven Suite 593 Warner Robins WI, 68085-5440", "deliveryTo": "Earl Bruen" }, { "saleNo": "82483", "address": "6562 Dagmar Haven Suite 593 Warner Robins WI, 68085-5440", "deliveryTo": "Harold Kuhn" }, { "saleNo": "53731", "address": "33194 Royal Track Suite 501 Enid CO, 57355", "deliveryTo": "Kristopher Bayer" }, { "saleNo": "12285", "address": "183 Lazaro Meadow Suite 841 Council Bluffs AL, 52499", "deliveryTo": "Cassandra Mueller" }, { "saleNo": "23404", "address": "89319 Witting Green Suite 924 Portland MN, 74633-9170", "deliveryTo": "Chris Thiel Sr." }, { "saleNo": "70528", "address": "2410 Zaria Forges Suite 936 St. Louis GA, 94962-5376", "deliveryTo": "Glenda Larson" } ]

let result = Object.entries(data.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  if(!acc[obj.address]) {
    acc[obj.address] = {
      saleNo: {},
      deliveryTo: {}
    };
  }
  acc[obj.address].saleNo[obj.saleNo] = true;
  acc[obj.address].deliveryTo[obj.deliveryTo] = true;
  return acc;
}, {})).map(arr => {
  let address = arr[0];
  let o = arr[1];
  return {
    saleNo: Object.keys(o.saleNo).sort(),
    address: address,
    deliveryTo: Object.keys(o.deliveryTo).sort()
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

So what about

```js
let result = new Array();

for (let dataIndex = 0, dataMax = data.length; dataIndex < dataMax; dataIndex++) {
    let address = data[dataIndex]["address"];

    let target = null;

    for (let resultIndex = 0, resultMax = result.length; resultIndex < resultMax; resultIndex++) {
        if (result[resultIndex].address == address) {
            target = result[resultIndex];
            break;
        }
    }

    if (target == null) {
        result.push({ address: address, saleNo: new Array(), deliveryTo: new Array() });
        target = result[result.length - 1];
    }

    target.saleNo.push(data[dataIndex].saleNo);
    target.deliveryTo.push(data[dataIndex].deliveryTo);
}
```

not doing anything clever? Result is not exactly the desired result, because

1. Fields `saleNo` and `deliveryTo` are always an `Array` even if there's just one value - you could adapt the example on first adding a string, and if it's not `undefined`, checking if it's an `Array` to simply add the new value, or otherwise replace the string with an `Array` that contains the first value. Not elegant, but easy to read/follow what's happening. Problem of course would be that on reading the `result`, you again have to handle this variance, instead of just always having an `Array`.

Comment: this is very helpful thank you! would love to have the `address` key back though rather than the address as the key any suggestions?

Comment: Updated, at the expense of the stupid/lazy extra inner loop (OK, maybe there's a search/find function on value/member, or even more advanced language constructs, here just doing something quick&simple&dirty).

Comment: This can be slow for a large data set, e.g. O(n*n) because of the nested for loops

Comment: Absolutely! :-( :-) Was not the desired result to use the address as an array index for fast lookup, also didn't make a separate address-to-index mapping array which would then grow memory. Therefore there's now your answer/solution :-)